# escape quotes in JSON object generated in js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I've tried every possible combination and looked at every possible question and nothing is working for me. 
I've got an active record object i'm getting in a js.erb file and turning into json:

```
var university_list = "<%= University.select([:name,:id]).to_json.html_safe %>"
```

and I get a string with unescaped quotes.
What i've tried:

**raw,h** - give a no method error

**j** - makes the result just disappear

**single quotes + JSON.parse** - unexpected token error

This sounds like it should have an easy solution, but what is it?!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: should university list be an object or a string?

Comment: It should be an object. You can see the solution that ended up working for me, though i don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i got it working, but the solution is really confusing me:

```
var university_list = <%= University.select([:name,:id]).to_json.html_safe %>
```

I was sure erb code in javascript has to be written in quotes? right??

Comment: No JSON is actually valid javascript, you can use it to create basic javascript objects directly: `var myobj = {"property": "value"};`

Comment: but is it legal to write erb directly without quotes? if so, why is it written in quotes in so many other cases (I'm referring to js.erb files)

Comment: Typically you only embed dynamic strings in js.erb (hence the quotations), but you can dynamically construct any valid js code (be careful with untrusted user input though)